# How can I get my columns renamed (alias) in my gridview?

Tags: asp.net, alias

I'm a bit stumped here trying to change the alias of the column names for C# asp.net page in Visual Studio 2012.  This page let's users search/filter filter data by columns, TankNum, CL and date range.  I want the gridview column name of TankNum to be Tank.

The full code is below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CellPadding="5" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#989898" ForeColor="white" />

     </asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=Computer\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True"

SelectCommand="SELECT TankNum, GD, CL FROM tblHistory2"
FilterExpression="GD >= '#{0}#' AND GD <= '#{1}#' AND TankNum LIKE '{2}%' AND CL LIKE '{3}%'">

    <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="Date" ControlID="tbDateFrom" Type="DateTime" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name=" Date" ControlID="tbDateTo" Type="DateTime" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtTankNum" Name="TankNum" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtCL" Name="CL" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
    </FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<br />

           <th>Tank</th>&nbsp;
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtTankNum" runat="server" Width="96px"> </asp:TextBox>Clock&nbsp; </td>
    <td ><asp:TextBox ID="txtCL" runat="server" Width="104px"></asp:TextBox></td>

        <p></p>

Enter the Date Range: 
<p>
</p>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="tbDateFrom" runat="server" ReadOnly = "false">01/01/2000</asp:TextBox></td>
    <td >&nbsp;</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="tbDateTo" runat="server" ReadOnly = "false">12/31/2017</asp:TextBox></td>
        <input type="submit" id="Submit1" runat="server" />

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to do:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT TankNum AS Tank, GD, CL FROM tblHistory2"
```

but I get this error: Cannot find column [TankNum].

Again, this works fine I just can't figure how to change the alias names of the columns.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You are aliasing TankNum to Tank, so the ControlParameter needs to match.  Try this:SELECT TankNum, GD, CL FROM tblHistory2 and then <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtTankNum" Name="Tank" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />

Comment: Research `BoundFields` and/or `ItemTemplates`. It will give you much more control over the GridView and it's content. With those you can set the name of the Column yourself without changing the query.

Comment: Kevin, I tried your suggestion and nothing changed.

Comment: I also tried adding boundfields and it worked except it duplicated the columns.

Comment: I figured it out.  I had AutoGenerateColumns="true" and it needed to be false.